# Finding the size of screen using JS on a 4k monitor

Tags: javascript, width, screen, monitor

I'm working on a photo carousel. The intent is to display x pictures on one row where x is dependent on the viewport size. By viewport I mean the area inside the browser's window less scroll bars. The photos are re-sized to a width of 200 If the viewport width is 2000 I can get 10 photos (200*10=2000) (I kept the arithmetic easy)

My screen resolution is 3840x2160. I expanded the browser to take up the entire screen.  When I use: $(window).width() i come up with 1707 and with  screen.width I come up with 1707. Definitely not 3840.

When I resize the browser so that it's taking up about half the screen I get:
$(window).width() of 929 and with screen.width 1706.

For browsers I'm using Edge, IE11, FF and Chrome 46 and I get roughly the same problem.

My desktop monitor is also 4k and from what I've read it consists of two panels of 1920x1080 for a total of 3840x2160. If that's true, on my laptop 4k monitor I should be getting a width of 1920 using screen.width, if I take up the entire screen but I'm not.

I need to take into account that most folks viewing this website will not have 4k monitors.

Any ideas on how I can get the screen width on a 4k monitor?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can make use of the `window.devicePixelRatio` property.

It should give you `1`, `2`, etc. Multiply `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` by this value.

```
var width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
var height = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

On my Dell laptop with a 4K UHD screen (3840 * 2160) display resolution, with Windows display settings configured to have a 250% scale and layout, I get the following results:

[image]

[image]

MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the windows' dimensions :

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
```

To get the screen's dimensions :

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
```

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my post, screen.width gives me 1707. With the browser window maxed using window.innerWidth, I get 1707 also. Both are 1707. I'm assuming the dimensions are in pixels. It's a 4K or UHD laptop.

Comment: That is very strange... I will search the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should report me for my 4K monitor the screen resolution **3840 x 2160**. In fact, I get:

- screen.width=2560
- screen.height=1440
- document.querySelector('html').clientWidth=2526
- window.innerWidth=2526
- window.outerWidth=2575
- document.querySelector('html').clientHeight=1301
- window.innerHeight=1301
- window.outerHeight=1415
- screen.availWidth=2560
- screen.availHeight=1400

40 pixels is the Windows 10 Taskbar at the bottom of the desktop.